# How to remove solid white horizontal bar at bottom of Android webview when scrolling?

Tags: android, css, webview

My Android application comprises of only a webview, and only on Lollipop (5.0), I've noticed this issue where scrolling in the webview will result in this solid white horizontal bar appearing at the bottom of the page. When I stop scrolling, the horizontal bar fades out. Is there a webview setting that I can set to prevent this bar from appearing at all?

Before Scrolling:
[image: before scroll]

While Scrolling:
[image: while scroll]

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activityMainImageview"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/portrait" />

        <com.whil.whil.VideoEnabledWebView
            android:id="@+id/activityMainWebview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: Thank you everyone for your comments, but the question linked regarding hiding a scroll bar does not apply here as this bar that appears is not a scroll bar, so none of the solutions mentioned in the other question works here.

Comment: `webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);` looks like what you want. Or even `android:scrollbars="none"` from the XML

Comment: I've edited my original question to include images to clarify the white horizontal bar that appears.

Comment: Share your XML layout so we can see if you have anything wrong there.

Comment: I've attached my XML layout.

Comment: For reference purposes, if anyone is having this problem, remove webview.setBuiltInZoomControls in your activity and you should no longer have this mysterious white horizontal bar appear when scrolling.